# How to break lines of s.th. like a minipage at smallest width possible without the minipage exceeding a given recommended height?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, paragraphs

I use LaTeX 2e.  I have material for horizontal mode.

Is there an environment similar to minipage with syntax similar to

```
\begin{SmallestWidthAtRecommendedHeight}[⟨Outer Position⟩]{⟨Maximum Width⟩}{⟨Recommended Height⟩}[⟨Inner Position⟩]
⟨Content of the environment⟩
\end{SmallestWidthAtRecommendedHeight}
```

, and where line-breaking is done with the *⟨Content of the environment⟩* as described below?

Break the lines of the *⟨Content of the environment⟩* in a box of the smallest width possible without the height of that box exceeding the *⟨Recommended Height⟩*.
If that smallest width is larger than *⟨Maximum Width⟩*, then instead break the lines of the *⟨Content of the environment⟩* in a box of width *⟨Maximum Width⟩* no matter if the height of the resulting box exceeds the *⟨Recommended Height⟩* or not.

I already looked at packages [varwidth](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) and [pbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/pbox), but they both don't work the way I have in mind:

[varwidth](https://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) does not typeset the box at minimum-width, but typesets the box with line-wrapping at given width and then checks if the result would also fit into a box of smaller width without linebreaks/height being changed.

[pbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/pbox) does not let you provide a *⟨Maximum Width⟩* for the length of its lines but lets you provide a *⟨Minimum Width⟩* and typesets the box with lines wrapped as short as possible but not shorter than *⟨Minimum Width⟩*.

I need: Wrap lines as short as possible at *⟨Recommended Height⟩*, but without lines being longer than *⟨Maximum Width⟩*. In case the width of lines at *⟨Recommended Height⟩* would exceed *⟨Maximum Width⟩*, wrap lines to the length *⟨Maximum Width⟩* no matter if *⟨Recommended Height⟩* is exceeded or not.

Comment: Do to the quantum behavior of line breaking, the only way to do this is iterate over widths.  Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496102/squeeze-paragraph-such-that-lines-have-similar-width