# Making nodes in tikz of same height

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want the boxes to be of the same height, not width. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
\tikzset{
%Define standard arrow tip
>=stealth',
%Define style for boxes
punkt/.style={
      rectangle,
      rounded corners,
      draw=black, very thick,
      text width=6.5em,
      minimum height=4cm,
      text centered}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]

\node[name=dummy] (dummy) {};
\node[punkt, name=oracle, left = 4cm of dummy] (oracle) {Oracle circuit $O_H$ providing access to $H_{xy}$};
\node[punkt, name=block, left = 0cm of dummy] (block) {$U_H$, block encoding of $H_{xy}$, which implements ${\ket{\psi}\mapsto H\ket{\psi}}$};
\node[punkt, name=algo, left = -4cm of dummy] (algo) {A circuit built upon the usage of $U_H$, which implements ${\ket{\psi}\mapsto f(H)\ket{\psi}}$ for some matrix function $f$};

\draw [-stealth] (oracle) edge[bend left=0, every node/.style={left=2cm}] []  (block);
\draw [-stealth] (block) edge[bend left=0, every node/.style={left=2cm}] []  (algo);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Increasing the `minimum height` leads to the following results:

[image]

Which is not what I need, since I don't want to change the first box height, and instead just want to make the second and third boxes wider.

Comment: Please always try to write a full compilable example instead of a code snippet. My guess is that you should add a `minimum height=...` in the definition of `punkt` style

Comment: We need to se preamble of document with this picture. There , we guess, are defined  picture elements style.

Comment: Fixed, please see the updated question.

Comment: Still missing preamble of document, which produce showed image. We need to see MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: If I'm seeing this right, you want [How to break lines of s.th. like a minipage at smallest width possible without the minipage exceeding a given recommended height?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517962) for nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{braket}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{
>=Stealth,
punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw, very thick, inner sep=8pt, align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node[punkt] (oracle) {Oracle circuit\\$O_H$ providing\\access to $H_{xy}$};
\node[punkt, right=of oracle] (block) {$U_H$, block encoding $H_{xy}$,\\which implements of\\${\ket{\psi}\mapsto H\ket{\psi}}$};
\node[punkt, right=of block] (algo) {A circuit built upon the usage of $U_H$,\\which implements ${\ket{\psi}\mapsto f(H)\ket{\psi}}$ for\\some matrix function $f$};
\draw[->] (oracle) -- (block);
\draw[->] (block) -- (algo);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three boxes with text and arrows]

Answer (score 2):

A bit rude solution, which require some manual tweak of nodes width:

[image]

In above image I first define width of the first node text line so, that complete text is spread in three lines., width of the second node is wide approximately 5/3 mail width (for this is text longer) of width of the first node, etc.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth},
   box/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners, align=left,
                 text width=#1, on chain, join=by arr}
                    ]
\node   [box=7em] {Oracle circuit\\
               $O_H$ providing\\ access to $H_{xy}$};
\node   [box=1.6*7em] {$U_H$, block encoding $H_{xy}$, \\
               which implements of \\
               ${\ket{\psi}\mapsto H\ket{\psi}}$};
\node   [box=2.4*7em] {A circuit built upon the usage of $U_H$, \\
               which implements ${\ket{\psi}\mapsto f(H)\ket{\psi}}$ for \\
               some matrix function $f$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

You can calculate factors of nodes width so, that first you measure length of text in each node and than calculate ratio between them.In above MWE I first estimate text length and then (manually) calculate ratios between them.