# Page numbering at the bottom right of the page, when the page margin is very small

Tags: margins, page-numbering

How to add the page numbering at the bottom right of the page, when the page margin is very small?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Firrst, printers can't actually handle a 3mm margin.  Once you get past page 9, you will have to overlap the text.   Do you want to leave a gap in the lower right corner in which to fit the page number?  Somewhay related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553233/apply-parshape-from-the-last-line-of-a-paragraph

Comment: I am open to several solutions.. thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reduce `\footskip` you can theoretically squeeze in the page foot, although whether things print correctly this close to the edge depends on things, for viewing a pdf though that isn't an issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\footskip{1pt}
\def\thepage{\smash{\raisebox{.2pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David! ....and, can the number be placed on the right (or left) side of the page, still at the bottom I mean ?

Comment: @Ommo yes just use fancyhdr package or define `\@oddfoot` directly

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)