# Page numbering at the bottom right of the page, when the page margin is extremely small

Tags: margins, page-numbering

This is a follow-up from [Page numbering at the bottom right of the page, when the page margin is very small](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713274/page-numbering-at-the-bottom-right-of-the-page-when-the-page-margin-is-very-sma/713288?noredirect=1#comment1772859_713288).

Based on the solution provided by @David Carlisle (related to the page numbering at the bottom *center* of the page), I tried to move the page numbering to the bottom *right* corner of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left   = 0.2cm,
        right  = 0.2cm,
        top    = 0.1cm,
        bottom = 0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\footskip{1pt}
\def\thepage{\smash{\raisebox{.2pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it works properly only when `bottom = 0.5cm` or larger than 0.5mm.

Is there a way to make the page numbering work for `bottom = 0.2cm`? Maybe with some overlap with the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must increse the `raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left   = 0.2cm,
        right  = 0.2cm,
        top    = 0.1cm,
        bottom = 0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \pagestyle{plain}
\setlength\footskip{1pt}
\def\thepage{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)